# How this program compiled and run successfully?

Tags: java

The below program compiled successfully and run without any errors. As per my understanding is should have thrown error in line 4. Can somebody explain?

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // my favorite website is
        http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting gives this problem away.  You can see the label and the comment have different colours ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not an error, "http:" works here as the name of the label and "//" starts the comments which is ignored.